# How can I open up a mobile version of Google in Pycharm using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, mobile, pycharm

I got some code together that lets me view the mobile version of Instagram, but whenever I try to put the code into a class and run the class, it fails. I have one Class for writing my methods, and another Class for calling the methods. When I run the second class, the chromedriver will open chrome, but it won't call the instagram URL.

this is the code that works

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = { "deviceName": "iPhone X" }
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", 
mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/~~/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://instagram.com/")
```

I tried making a class to hold the code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver

mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "iPhone X"}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", 
mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/~~/chromedriver',
                      chrome_options=chrome_options)
class IGFrame:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def open_ig(self):
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
```

and then this was the class to call the method

```
from version1.pages.basic_methods import *

class TestSetUp:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_mobileViewOfIG(self):
        methods = IGFrame(self.driver)
        methods.open_ig()
```

What I was aiming for was to have the driver setup and the method to call the URL in the IGFrame class, and then I would call the method from the TestSetUp class. What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Comment: indent your methods correctly

Comment: my indentations are good, i dont know what else is the issue

Comment: your code looks good. try giving an absolute executable path for chrome driver. it should resolve the issue